# Center text without footnote symbol offsetting text

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

In Word 2013, how do I center text in a table column and have footnote symbol that does not offset the centered text?
Below is a pictured example of what I'm talking about.

[image: column]

The asterisks do not move the numbers out of center with the numbers that do not have an asterisk.

Comment: I don't have 10 reputation, so I couldn't post the image in the question where it belongs.  Maybe someone with reputation can edit the question and put it there.